# Where is /sys/subsystem as described in Linux kernel doc?

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel

Quote from https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysfs-rules.txt:

> [...] It is planned to merge all three classification directories into one place at /sys/subsystem, following the layout of the bus directories. All buses and classes, including the converted block subsystem, will show up there.
>
> The devices belonging to a subsystem will create a symlink in the "devices" directory at /sys/subsystem/<name>/devices.
>
> If /sys/subsystem exists, /sys/bus, /sys/class and /sys/block can be ignored. If it does not exist, you always have to scan all three places, as the kernel is free to move a subsystem from one place to the other, as long as the devices are still reachable by the same subsystem name.

Well, when I try to learn the layout of the /sys filesystem of Linux kernel, I see no /sys/subsystem directory in my Ubuntu OS (I use Ubuntu 14.04).

I did a quick Google search and only found an [LKML discussion](https://lkml.org/lkml/2010/3/31/22) about the directory unification, but I don't see anything else beside Kay Sievers' note. (A [git log](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/log/Documentation/sysfs-rules.txt) on Documentation/sysfs-rules.txt also shows it's by him, too.)

My question is, do I miss anything? Why is the directory not available? Or is the directory merge never actually happened in kernel development and is the document wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think the key part of the document you quoted from is here:

> If /sys/subsystem exists, /sys/bus, /sys/class and /sys/block can be
>     ignored. If it does not exist, you always have to scan all three
>     places, as the kernel is free to move a subsystem from one place to
>     the other, as long as the devices are still reachable by the same
>     subsystem name.

Whilst looking for other references of the /sys/subsystem directory, I found the following comment in the file `99-systemd.rules.in`

> We need a hardware independent way to identify network devices. We 
>     use the /sys/subsystem path for this. Current vanilla kernels don't  actually support that 
>     hierarchy right now, however upcoming kernels will....

So I imagine that it will be included in later kernels.